# Broadcast Receiver every 5 minutes to get wifi signal

Tags: android, android-broadcast

friends

I m pretty new here and for android as well. I would like to know is it possible or not  to get Wifi signal every 5 -10 minutes, I have heard we can use broadcast receiver but I don't know is it okay or not to refresh every 5 or 10 minutes

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for that, you can taste the abstract status of the network to get information if you are connected or not and if it's mobile or WiFi using [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html), describe in details in this android [article](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

Or you can use the [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html), that allows you to:

- [Lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#createWifiLock%28java.lang.String%29)/[Unlock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#createWifiLock%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) Wifi network
- [Turn on/off](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#setWifiEnabled%28boolean%29) WiFi network
- [Change description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#updateNetwork%28android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration%29) of specific connection
- [Ask for scan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan%28%29) - Manually cause the device to scan for WiFi networks.
- [Get information about all the networks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks%28%29) detected by device
- And more...

For part of the operations you will have to request

- [**ACCESS_WIFI_STATE**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_WIFI_STATE)
- [**CHANGE_WIFI_STATE**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)

Comment: well, how about when getting the signal 5 times and stop it? is it okay?

Comment: @user2982616 I don't think so. There is an event mechanism, and in my opinion you should use it, even if it's just 5 times.

Comment: I found the app named Wi-Fi Analytics (in Play store). It can refresh  whatever you want, do you know how it works?

Comment: @user2982616 They are using WifiManager, I updated the answer to show you how.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

```
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, StatusQueryServiceStartReceiver.class);
    // Schedule the alarm!If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled.
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        0,//cal.getTimeInMillis(), 
        REPEAT_TIME, pending);
    // service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
    // REPEAT_TIME, pending);
```

StatusQueryServiceStartReceiver is a broadcast receiver

Comment: Let me try out, I have not used this before, if it works, it s gonna be good idea :)